# rotating camera with mouse movement using SceneKit on OS X

Tags: macos, scenekit

As the title may suggest I'm attempting to set up my own event handler to rotate my camera node using scene kit. I can't seem to find any good tutorials out there for how to translate "mouseMoved" events into smooth camera motion.

Where can I start this process, is there working code somewhere I can look at or a recommendation on how to accomplish this?

```
class gameView: NSView
{
    var sceneView: SCNView!
    var camera: SCNNode!
    var ground: SCNNode!
    var light: SCNNode!
    var button: SCNNode!
    var sphere1: SCNNode!
    var sphere2: SCNNode!


    override func mouseMoved(theEvent: NSEvent)
    {
        var x = self.camera.rotation.x
        var y = self.camera.rotation.y
        var z = self.camera.rotation.z
        var w = self.camera.rotation.w
        //WHAT TO DO
        //something happens to x, y, z and w based on mouse movement to make the camera respond by rotating with the mouse
                self.camera.rotation = SCNVector4(x: x, y: y, z: z, w: w)

    }
    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect)
    {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
        self.becomeFirstResponder()
        //self.enterFullScreenMode(NSScreen.mainScreen()!, withOptions: nil)
        let trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: self.bounds, options: (NSTrackingAreaOptions.MouseMoved | NSTrackingAreaOptions.MouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingAreaOptions.ActiveAlways), owner: self, userInfo: nil)
        self.addTrackingArea(trackingArea)
        var image = NSImage(named: "rockTexture.jpg");
        var imgArray = [image!, image!, image!, image!, image!, image!]
        // Drawing code here.
        sceneView = SCNView(frame: self.frame)
        //sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
        sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
        self.addSubview(sceneView)
        CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0));
        let groundGeometry = SCNFloor()
        groundGeometry.reflectivity = 0
        let groundMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        groundMaterial.diffuse.contents = image
        groundMaterial.reflective.contents = imgArray
        groundGeometry.materials = [groundMaterial]
        ground = SCNNode(geometry: groundGeometry)

        let camera = SCNCamera()
        camera.zFar = 10000
        self.camera = SCNNode()
        self.camera.camera = camera
        self.camera.position = SCNVector3(x: -20, y: 15, z: 20)
        let constraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: ground)
        constraint.gimbalLockEnabled = true
        //self.camera.constraints = [constraint]

        let ambientLight = SCNLight()
        ambientLight.color = NSColor.darkGrayColor()
        ambientLight.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient
        self.camera.light = ambientLight

        let spotLight = SCNLight()
        spotLight.type = SCNLightTypeSpot
        spotLight.castsShadow = true
        spotLight.spotInnerAngle = 70.0
        spotLight.spotOuterAngle = 90.0
        spotLight.zFar = 500
        light = SCNNode()
        light.light = spotLight
        light.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 25, z: 25)
        light.constraints = [constraint]

        let sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 1.5)
        let sphereMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        sphereMaterial.diffuse.contents = NSColor.greenColor()
        sphereGeometry.materials = [sphereMaterial]
        sphere1 = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeometry)
        sphere1.position = SCNVector3(x: -15, y: 1.5, z: 0)
        sphere2 = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeometry)
        sphere2.position = SCNVector3(x: 15, y: 1.5, z: 0)

        let buttonGeometry = SCNBox(width: 4, height: 1, length: 4, chamferRadius: 0)
        let buttonMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        buttonMaterial.diffuse.contents = NSColor.redColor()
        buttonGeometry.materials = [buttonMaterial]
        button = SCNNode(geometry: buttonGeometry)
        button.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0.5, z: 15)

        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(self.camera)
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(ground)
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(light)
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(button)
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere1)
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere2)
    }
    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent)
    {
        var location = self.convertPoint(theEvent.locationInWindow, fromView: nil)
        let hitResults = sceneView.hitTest(location, options: nil)
        if hitResults?.count > 0 {
            let result = hitResults![0] as! SCNHitTestResult
            let node = result.node
            //node.removeFromParentNode()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code to make it easier to understand the problem.

Comment: My code has been added.